# Why is APP_PATH preventing me from starting WEBrick

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, webrick

I type the `rails server` command in my app directory and receive this error:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH /Users/user/Repositories/simple_cms/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

I then navigated to the `bin/rails` directory to find out what **APP_PATH** was. This is what I found on line 6: `APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)`

Not wanting to directly alter this file, I followed advice found on github and commented the gem `'spring', group: :development` out of my `Gemfile`

I tried the `rails server` command  once more and received the same error, so I uncommented `'spring', group: :development` and tried `rails server` one last time.

This time around, I second time around an entirely different error... http://pastebin.com/bPYgufBH

Why can't I start my server?

Comment: I had this problem and the cause is configuration on the `database.yml` was different of adapter in `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 6):

Run `rake rails:update:bin` and you'll receive an error.

Then you'll have to create a symbol link:
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

I addressed the conflicts, run `rails server` again and WEBrick should work like a charm.

Comment: I got `ln: Operation not permitted`